# CSS - remove left panel and always keep header with search,cart link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove left panel as shown here : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_clothing_store&stacked=h

and want to keep the header always with logo and search,cart.

What I have tried so far: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1984XJ1SGG1

When the screen width is less then I can see the header but when its large the header disappear.

Comment: did you need menu ?, If not. Please find the code at https://codepen.io/kavinrajsi/pen/daQNeY @rajesh

Comment: perfect. Thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.w3-sidebar a {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.w3-wide {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;}

body{
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.fixed-top{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 15000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
<div class="w3-main">
  <!-- Top header -->
  <header class="fixed-top w3-container w3-xlarge">
    <p class="w3-left"><b>LOGO</b></p>
    <p class="w3-right">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart w3-margin-right"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </p>
  </header>

  <!-- Image header -->
  <div class="w3-display-container w3-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans.jpg" alt="Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-text-white" style="padding:24px 48px">
      <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-hide-small">New arrivals</h1>
      <h1 class="w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">New arrivals</h1>
      <h1 class="w3-hide-small">COLLECTION 2016</h1>
      <p><a href="#jeans" class="w3-button w3-black w3-padding-large w3-large">SHOP NOW</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-container w3-text-grey" id="jeans">
    <p>8 items</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Product grid -->
  <div class="w3-row w3-grayscale">
    <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <p>Ripped Skinny Jeans<br><b>$24.99</b></p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/jeans2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <p>Mega Ripped Jeans<br><b>$19.99</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-display-container">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/jeans2.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <span class="w3-tag w3-display-topleft">New</span>
          <div class="w3-display-middle w3-display-hover">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black">Buy now <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Mega Ripped Jeans<br><b>$19.99</b></p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <p>Washed Skinny Jeans<br><b>$20.50</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <p>Washed Skinny Jeans<br><b>$20.50</b></p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-display-container">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans4.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <span class="w3-tag w3-display-topleft">Sale</span>
          <div class="w3-display-middle w3-display-hover">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black">Buy now <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Vintage Skinny Jeans<br><b class="w3-text-red">$14.99</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans4.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <p>Vintage Skinny Jeans<br><b>$14.99</b></p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/jeans1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <p>Ripped Skinny Jeans<br><b>$24.99</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Subscribe section -->
  <div class="w3-container w3-black w3-padding-32">
    <h1>Subscribe</h1>
    <p>To get special offers and VIP treatment:</p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Enter e-mail" style="width:100%"></p>
    <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-red w3-margin-bottom">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="w3-padding-64 w3-light-grey w3-small w3-center" id="footer">
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <p>Questions? Go ahead.</p>
        <form action="/action_page.php" target="_blank">
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="Subject" required></p>
          <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" name="Message" required></p>
          <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <h4>About</h4>
        <p><a href="#">About us</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">We're hiring</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Support</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Find store</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Shipment</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Payment</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Gift card</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Return</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Help</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-col s4 w3-justify">
        <h4>Store</h4>
        <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i> Company Name</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> 0044123123</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> ex@mail.com</p>
        <h4>We accept</h4>
        <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cc-amex"></i> Amex</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-credit-card"></i> Credit Card</p>
        <br>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-snapchat w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <div class="w3-black w3-center w3-padding-24">Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" title="W3.CSS" target="_blank" class="w3-hover-opacity">w3.css</a></div>

  <!-- End page content -->
</div>

<!-- Newsletter Modal -->
<div id="newsletter" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom" style="padding:32px">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
      <i onclick="document.getElementById('newsletter').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge"></i>
      <h2 class="w3-wide">NEWSLETTER</h2>
      <p>Join our mailing list to receive updates on new arrivals and special offers.</p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Enter e-mail"></p>
      <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-red w3-margin-bottom" onclick="document.getElementById('newsletter').style.display='none'">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```